# Why does vibrational frequency influence quantum tunneling of a proton?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, kinetics

> Furthermore, consideration of the tunneling in the framework of the Wigner theory assumes that the tunneling factor is small. However, the $\ce{O-H}$ frequency is very high ($\gg k_\mathrm{B}T/h$), and the H atom tunneling under a potential energy barrier when proceeding either from a ground or from other excited vibration levels may be significant.

**Source:** [German, E. D.; Sheintuch, M. Kinetics of Catalytic OH Dissociation on Metal Surfaces. *J. Phys. Chem. C* **2012,** *116* (9), 5700–5709. DOI:10.1021/jp2106499](http://doi.org/10.1021/jp2106499).

Why does a higher frequency influence the quantum tunneling effect?

Answer (score 8):

It is not the frequency *per se* but the mass that is important,; the probability of tunnelling an energy *E* is given by

$$p(E)=\exp \left(-\frac{4\pi\sqrt{m}}{h^2}\int_{x_a}^{x_b}\sqrt{V(x)-E}\;dx \right)$$

where $x_a$ and $x_b$ are two points either side of the potential barrier through which tunnelling occurs. The integral is in effect a measure of the area of the potential $V$ above position $x_a$ to $x_b$ through which tunnelling can occur.

As *m* increases, for a given potential barrier and energy, the tunnelling probability falls.

Comment: But why does the author say it that way and compare it with kT/h?

Comment: @wangge Don't know other than $k_BT/h$ has units of $s^{-1}$ but in this case is not a frequency but units of a first order rate constant.

Comment: I believe the comparison to $k_BT/h$ is more commonly talked about as the dimensionless ratio $\hbar\omega/k_bT$. I have seen this comparison made quite a few times when discussing nuclear quantum effects, as it essentially measures whether or not we are in the classical regime where thermal effects will be most important. For something like $\ce{O-H}$, this ratio is quite large even at room temperature. Also note that this shows up in the tunneling rate given above by means of $E$ which will be quite close to the vibrational energy of the $\ce{O-H}$. Hence talk of the vibrational frequency.

Comment: @jheindel good point.